# Is there a name for the topology of a totally disconnected space where every point is arbitrarily close to all the others?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is there a name for the topology of a totally disconnected space where every point is arbitrarily close to all the others?

This may actually be the $xy$ question.  This is the specific example I'm interested in:

Let $\Bbb Q,d$ have the standard topology as a one-dimensional euclidean metric.

Now glue together parts of $\Bbb Q$ as follows:  Let $2^m3^nq\sim q:m,n\in\Bbb Z$

That enables us to think of the 5-rough rationals as a transversal of $X=\Bbb Q/\langle2,3\rangle$.

But because $2^m3^n$ is dense in $\Bbb Q$, every set $\{x\cdot2^m3^n:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ comes arbitrarily close to every other set.  Or in other words $\inf \{d(y,z):y\in Y, z\in Z\}=0$ where $Y,Z\in \Bbb Q/\langle2,3\rangle$

Although we still have $\min\{d(y,z):y\in Y, z\in Z\}=0\iff y=z$ so we might recover some measure of distance between the cosets $d'$.

I'm seeing $\Bbb Q/\langle2,3\rangle,d'$ as a totally disconnected space where every point is arbitrarily close to all the others.

Is this a commonly encountered space and is there a better way to assign $\Bbb Q/\langle2,3\rangle$ a topology - given that I'm interested in the topological properties of the cosets?  Does the property of every elements being arbitrarily close render the topology essentially useless?

---

UPDATE: I think what I'm describing here is essentially the discrete topology since $d'$ assigns distance $0$ between $x,x$ and one can choose any arbitrary distance between distinct classes since $\min$ is not defined.

Comment: What are you studying this set for? This quotient space is not a metric space.

Comment: @D.Brogan I'm actually interested more in connectedness than distance. I'm studying an action over these sets of numbers and for any $z\in\Bbb Q$, the action acts uniformly on $2^m3^n z$. I'm trying to glue parts together to show the graph of the action connects certain subsets of $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would give quotients the quotient topology, that is, a subset $U \subseteq \mathbb Q / \sim$ is open iff its preimage $\pi^{-1}(U) \subseteq\mathbb Q$ is open. In particular the projection $\pi : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q / \sim$ is a continuous map. Now the open sets look like the following:

1. $\mathbb Q / \sim$ whose preimage is $\mathbb Q$
2. $\emptyset$ whose preimage is $\emptyset$
3. $\mathbb Q^\times / \sim$ whose preimage is $\mathbb Q^\times$
4. $\pm \mathbb Q^+ / \sim$ whose preimage is $\pm \mathbb Q^+$

If $U \neq \emptyset$ is open, then it contains without loss of generality $[x]$ with $x > 0$ and its preimage $x \in \pi^{-1}(U)$ is open. For all $y > 0$ by denseness of $\{2^n 3^m y \mid m, n \in \mathbb Z \} \subseteq \mathbb Q^+$, $\pi^{-1}(U)$ contains some $2^n 3^m y$ and thus $[y] \in U$. A similar argument for $x < 0$ shows that $U$ is of the form above.

In particular, your topological space is relatively boring.

Comment: Just checking I understand correctly; $\Bbb Q^\times=\Bbb Q\setminus0$, right?  The multiplicative group.

Comment: and b) list item 4. contains two distinct open sets, right?

Comment: @samerivertwice yes and yes.